# Delimit and join in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas

I have a range of data in Google Sheets, column A is a list of unique identifiers (eg "ABCD1"), column B is a delimited list of attributes of each (A,B,C...) . I want to produce a list of unique identifiers and every single attribute across 2 columns (for example, ABCD1 A).  Please help!

## raw data

[image]

## outcome

[image]

Comment: This is very possible.  I have a sort of technique i developed to do it, but I'd need a sample sheet to work off of, rather than just an image.  if possible, put the sample values in the columns they're really in in the real sheet.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(A1&"♦"&TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(B1; ",")); "♦"))
```

[image: 0]